# How can I get all three Kalos starters?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I just got this game, and I picked Fennekin, the fire Pokémon as my starter. Is there a way to get the other two starters too, or am I limited to only getting one?

Comment: Trading, I guess. If you don't have friends to trade with, you could try using the GTS (Global Trading Station).

Comment: After you beat the elite four, you do get the starter weak to yours. I picked Fennekin to start with, so then I got Chespin after beating the game.

Comment: Kind of related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135364/getting-all-kanto-starters-in-x-and-y. I'm pretty sure it applies for Kalos starters too

Comment: Sorry am new to this site  I love the pokemon games but my friends don't have them so thanks 4 any help u can give me

Comment: There are ways to get 3DS friends without having actual real friends playing Pokémon. Lots of places on the Internet offer friend code exchanges. Also Haidro is right, this does apply to the Kalos Starters as well. All 6 can be found in the friend safari.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few different ways to obtain all three Kalos starts.

1. Your rival will trade you the starter that is weak to your starter after beating the Elite Four. 
   -**NOTE**: You need a spare Pokemon to trade for it, but you should have one.
2. Friend Safari can give you the 1st evolution of a starter if you are lucky with who you add as a friend.
3. Wonder Trading can result in one of the Pokemon you are looking for, but it requires lots of luck, and lots of attempts.
4. Using the GTS is an easy way. If you breed your start and put it to trade for one of the ones you are looking for, it could be traded.
5. If you have a friend who has a different starter who would be willing breed it and trade one, then trading is another way.

Now out of those, the GTS is the best way to get the starters, seeing that there are many breeders and collectors who are willing to trade their starters for other Pokemon.

It really takes lots of patience, and to look at the right places.

Answer (score 5):

Just like the previous Pokemon games, you have to trade with others to obtain the other two starters. I've actually gotten very lucky with the new Wonder Trade option on the PSS, so you could try that out if trading isn't proving lucky.

Comment: I never get anything good during the wonder trade. Usually I get a Bidoof, Azuril, or a Weedle. I usually have to go to GTS to get something good.

Comment: Yeah, Wonder Trade is really more miss than hit. I found the best way was to offer something rare-ish (I used a Sylveon; you can get Eevees surprisingly early) in exchange for a Ditto, breed your starter and trade the babies for the other starters. GTS is amazing

Comment: not entirely correct. you can get a second starter after beating the elite four. It will be the one yours is strong against i.e. if you start with Froakie, you'll get Fennekin and so on

Answer (score 3):

Not only trade!

**You can trade and earn another starter** - in my case Fennekin - **after you beat the game** (win with Elite Four) [from one of your friends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/135474/10679) when you go out from home. This **might be** connected with beeing nice to your friends all game and choosing "nice" dialogue options.

I'm not sure if you can earn third starter after beating Elite Four second time... but it will be great :)

Comment: You earn the starter weak to yours after becoming champion, you can trade your "friendly rival" (the girl with cutoffs) for any pokemon you have.

Answer (score 0):

You go to friend safari then you go to the type island you want and you can get for example ect (charmander) in the fire island or braiken 
Or go to water island and get watorle or froakie a second evolution or go to grass island and get ivysaur or chespin

Comment: What you get in the [Friend Safari](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friend_Safari) depends entirely on what Friend Codes you have registered.

Answer (score -1):

I used wonder trade to get Chespin and Fennekin (I chose Froakie). If you are lucky, you can get the other starters trough wonder trade.

It took me a long time to get all the starters, so it isn't going to be easy this way.

Comment: If you add an answer months later, you could at least *try* to provide some new information.

Answer (score -4):

A good way to get Pokemon like the Kantos starters is:First you will need to have the HM Surf and Waterfall i guess and then go to Route 22 Surf on the river and go down the waterfalluse the Old Rod on the river you will aways have Magikarp capture as many as possible and trade them by Wonder Trade and enjoy!

Comment: Downvoted for abusing the system.

Comment: I don't know that that's necessarily a *good* way to do it, since it relies on people wonder trading starters, which does happen, yes, but people also flood wonder trade with Magikarps...

Comment: If you're going to catch just about anything only to Wonder Trade it, you can at least catch stuff available late in the game. There is simply absolutely no reason to deliberately catch bad Pokémon only to abuse the system and deceive others who don't. Also, breeding can be faster and easier (and is certainly cheaper because you don't need balls) and if you breed something nice (like fossils or your own starter), people will actually be happy about what they got from you. If there's no difference for you, why not do what's better for others?

Comment: @scenia, not to mention, you can obtain Shinies through breeding, and even go fo those good IVs while you are at it.